# C# End image movement by pressing key

Tags: c#, winforms, keyboard-events

I am new to C# and wanted to know how I could make it so that once the user presses the enter key, the current location of the image becomes its fixed location. I was thinking that the best way to do it would be using a while loop. Help would really be appreciated. The following is my code for moving my image:

```
private void pictureBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    int x = pictureBox1.Location.X;
    int y = pictureBox1.Location.Y;

    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right) x += 50;
        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left) x -= 50;
        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up) y -= 50;
        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down) y += 50;
        pictureBox1.Location = new Point(x, y); 
    }

}
```

Comment: You could use the KeyPress instead of the KeyDown. If you want to use the key down, you might use a timer that checks of the arrow key is pressed and alter the positions.

Comment: The KeyDown event is fired on the control that has the focus.  PictureBox is special, it never gets the focus.  So your event handler never runs.  Best thing to do is to override the form's ProcessCmdKey() method, now focus no longer matters.  And you almost surely want to google "windows forms game loop".

Comment: @J.vanLangen Thank you for the help. Could you please explain the difference between KeyDown and KeyPree?

Comment: KeyDown will give an event ones a key is pressed.(only one event per key) The KeyPressed will give an event when a key is pressed, but also it will trigger keystrokes (like triggering the same key multiple times)

Comment: Ive changed to KeyPress but now I get this error: "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler' to 'System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventHandler'"  For my the following code:                              
 public Grid()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            KeyPress += new KeyEventHandler(pictureBox1_KeyPress);
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this solution i have used a global `bool` object and changed flag to `true` once an enter key is pressed.
I have a form with Picture Box and on the `form_KeyDown` event i placed your code with small change.

```
 bool bIsEnterKeyPressed = false;
 private void frmSampleJson_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            bIsEnterKeyPressed = true;
        }
        if (!bIsEnterKeyPressed)
        {
            int x = pictureBox1.Location.X;
            int y = pictureBox1.Location.Y;

            {
                if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right) x += 50;
                else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left) x -= 50;
                else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up) y -= 50;
                else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down) y += 50;
                pictureBox1.Location = new Point(x, y);
            }
        }
    }
```

Once enter is pressed the `bIsEnterKeyPressed` is changed to `true` and the position will not be changed after that.

Comment: This worked -Thank you!!! Would you mind telling me how I would make it so that after the Enter Key is pressed pictureBox2 can move using the arrow Keys and then once the Enter Key is pressed again pictureBox2 becomes in a fixed possition and pictureBox3 can move? Essentially I am creating a battleships game and I am trying to allow the user to place their ships using the arrow and enter keys.

Comment: Ok , so on `form_Load` use `for` loop to create PictureBox and  `Key_Down` event. As well Use `PictureBox.Tag` property to name each of them. Well `Key_Down` Event is fired , get the picture  box tag and use `if` loop to work on these conditions. just like a `bool` flag we used in our solution.